# Is parameter validation necessary in private function

Tags: java

Given there is a party and a java application to manage the people, below is the class to add person.

```
public enum ServiceType {
    DJ("DJ"), 
    Host("Host"), 
    Guest("Guest"), 
    Others("Others");
}

public void addHost(Person a) {
    this.addParticipant(a, Role.Host);
}

public void addDJ(Person a) {
    this.addParticipant(a, Role.DJ);
}

public void addGuest(Person a) {
    this.addParticipant(a, Role.Guest);
}

private void addParticipant(Person p, Role r);
```

**Is it necessary to check if the parameter role is valid in the private function addParticipant?**

If the check is needed, how can I coverage the exception line in the UT?

Comment: If the check is not needed, it may throw null pointer exception.

Comment: No, it is not necessary.

Comment: Can I coverage the exception line in the UT? Good code may include check for something that is believed to be impossible, to guard against future errors. This is known as *defensive* programming. As such, there will be code that is impossible to cover in testing. Accept that as part of life.

Comment: @Andreas why is it not needed ? If it is not checked in the public methods it may "it may throw null pointer exception".

Comment: If you checked validity in the public methods you could test it.

Comment: A public method can be called by *anybody*, and you have little control over that. A private method can only be called by other code in the same class, and you have *full* control over that code, so you can (theoretically) guarantee that private method is called correctly. Well, if you trust yourself and your fellow programmers, that is. Do you? If not, you probably *should* validate, to guard against code errors. BTW: Did you look up the meaning of *defensive programming*? You should, then you'd know what I'm talking about, and you wouldn't have to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a null check within a private method for the parameter. A private method cannot be accessed from outside the class and you (as the one writing the code) is responsible for passing correct inputs to it. This forms the *precondition* of thar private method.

But here, parameter `Role` is passed from within the same class. So, there is no need to check if it is null (unless you are explicitly passing null, in which case the mistake is on you).

What you should do is to validate if `Person` instance passed to the public methods is null by adding a null check in the public methods

This is also mentioned by Robert Martin in his book Clean Code - in Item 38: Check parameters for validity (**emphasis mine**)

> For an unexported method, you as the package author control the circumstances under which the method is called, so you can and should ensure that **only valid parameter values are ever passed in**. Therefore, non-public methods should generally check their parameters using assertions[..]